# Floating Point errors in Colt Java matrix libraries

Tags: java, matrix, floating-point, colt

How do I avoid floating point errors in financial calculations performed with Colt matrix libraries?

Answer (score 3):

Some essential reading about the nastiness of floating point types: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768)

And something more Java flavoured: [How Java’s Floating-Point Hurts Everyone Everywhere](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/JAVAhurt.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

One common technique is to use integers and keep track of the decimals yourself.
For example you can decide that all you currency amount will be represented with 3 decimal points accuracy. So instead of writing:

```
double dollars = 10.05d;
```

you write

```
int dollars = 10050;
```

and when you want to print the amount:

```
System.out.println( dollars/100d );
```

Answer (score 0):

For financials it's more common to use BigDecimal and related classes. float and doubles are in any case very susceptible to rounding errors.

You may want to look at [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-1.0/org/apache/commons/math/linear/BigMatrixImpl.html) if you decide to give BigDecimal a try.